# Puzzling behaviour of a specific figure-subplot conjunction in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, subplot

I wrote and am using a matlab program which, among other things, generate a large number of figures usually using the subplot command. [These figures represent molecule trajectories in single molecule experiments, their total number is not known in advance but typically amounts to a few hundreds.] It had worked absolutely smoothly up to this day, where I got the following error message:

> Error using subplot (line 159)
>   Requires valid axes handle for input.

After some hand-debugging I think I have isolated the problem as coming from the following sequence:

```
figure(i)
...
subplot(i)
```

Where i can be any integer. The easiest reproducible example would be:

```
i=211;
...
x=linspace(0,1,101);
figure(i)
subplot(211)
plot(x,x)
subplot(212)
plot(x,x)
```

The problem is identically triggered by setting i=212 in the above case. Obviously I could possibly dirty-quickly fix the problem with some

```
if i=212 || 211
  j=something-different-from-212-or-211;
else
  j=i;
end
figure(j)
...
```

But I would have liked to know if something more convenient/handy/elegant exists – also, I would be curious to know more, if possible, about the cause of this problem!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you creating multiple figures with multiple axes (subplots) or one figure with multiple axes?

Comment: I am creating multiple figures with multiple axes.

Typically, I have some loop running on an index i as above, and for each i I open a figure containing usually 2,3, or 4 subplots (depends).

(And I want not to close the previously generated figures)

Comment: Are you sure you should be using both `figure(i)` and `subplot(i)`, with the same indexing variable `i`? You might not have the same number of figures and number of axes in all those figures. If you have `N` figures, then use `n=1:N` with `figure(n)` to change/create figures and if there are `M` axes in a figure, then use a different subplot indexing variable for those `M` axes (depending on the subplot layout: the number of columns and rows of subplot axes).

Comment: I read you edited comment just now:
Loop over all figures:
`for n=1:N, figure(n), ..., end`. Within the loop, loop over the desired amount of subplots using a `for`-loop with at different counting variable, e.g. `j`.

Comment: Then there is perhaps something I don't understand about the subplot command/options: let us say I want for each figure output 'figure(n)' two subplots. Assuming, e.g., I want one on top and one below: am I then not bound to index the subplot command as 'subplot(211)...subplot(212)'?

Comment: It's strange, but when I run your easiest reproducible example, it works just fine. Maybe it has something to do with the versions we are using.

Comment: Haem, that's bothering. Which matlab version are you using? (I'm on R2015b)

Comment: You're using the `211` and `212` incorrectly: either use `subplot('211')`, which is a *char* input (text string), or use `subplot(2,1,1)`, which are three *double* inputs (numbers). The first number denotes the number of rows, the second the number of columns, the third the axes number to make the current axes (from left to right, top to bottom).

Comment: Also, don't use `i=211, figure(i), subplot(i)`, which is erroneous syntax. See my previous comment or the MATLAB documentation for the correct use of `subplot`.

Comment: Concerning your last comment, it was simply for being generic (the bug appearing  with `figure(312)...subplot(312)` but also `figure(211)...subplot(211)` etc.), but I do not actually call the subplot function as `subplot(i)`.

As for the previous one, thank you so much! I was indeed not using subplot correctly (after all those years...), and this fixes my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect its a "feature" of the many ways you can call `subplot` and the fact that old handles were also known as numbers, for example the following fails:

```
figure(211); subplot(211)
figure(212); subplot(212)
```

but:

```
 figure; subplot(211)
 figure; subplot(212)
```

are both okay.

In the 1st one what Matlab is doing is that it is parsing the input arguments to work out which of the ways to process. i.e. the 1st argument can also be an axes handle. e.g.

```
ax = subplot ( 211 )
% some other code and plot on other subplot
% you can then set the 1st subplot to be active again:
subplot ( ax );
```

The key item here is that the 1st argument to subplot can be many things...

In your original case where you had:

```
figure(211);
```

This means that when you pass in `211` in to the subplot

```
subplot(211)
```

It checks to see if its a `handle` -> and it is:

```
figure(211)
ishandle(211)
```

Then it checks to see if its an `axes` -> which is where it fails and triggers the error that you see.

I rarely use subplot at all and when I do I always use the syntax:

```
hFig = figure;
ax(p) = subplot(m,n,p,'Parent',hFig)
```

where I have the handle to gui objects and explicitly name them when operating on them.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer, it enlightens the whole thing.
(and see comments to the first post for the "appropriate syntax")

Comment: No problem - it was a quirky problem to look into! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can separate the parameters of function subplot:

```
figure(211);
subplot(2,1,1);
```